# Selecting the same field twice and joining to it twice in an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

| marketing_interaction |  |
| --- | --- |
| marketing_interaction_id | 1 |
| organization_id | 75 |
| contact_id | 18 |
| internal_person_id | 97 |
| description | Followup with client |

| person |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| person_id | 18 | 97 |
| first_name | John | Adam |
| last_name | Smith | Jones |

| organization |  |
| --- | --- |
| organization_id | 75 |
| name | Acme Corp. |

I am writing a query to return the following information:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0stI.png)

I can't get the first and last name fields to appear after the internal_person_id field. The marketing_interaction table has two fields that need to reference the person table. I can only get it to join with the person table once, even though I tried using aliases. I am also trying full outer joins, but on MySQL they won't work.

```
SELECT marketing_interaction.marketing_interaction_id, 
 marketing_interaction.organization_id, 
 organization.name, 
 marketing_interaction.contact_id, 
 person.first_name, 
 person.last_name, 
 marketing_interaction.internal_person_id, 
 p.first_name, 
 p.last_name, 
 marketing_interaction.description
FROM marketing_interaction
JOIN organization 
  ON marketing_interaction.organization_id=organization.organization_id
JOIN person 
  ON marketing_interaction.contact_id=person.person_id
JOIN person AS p 
  ON marketing_interaction.internal_person_id=p.person_id
```

Comment: Side note, you should alias all tables. That will make this much easier to read. And when inputting sample data from tables, input them as you see in a table. You inverted the data from columns to rows.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Clearly when pinned down this is likely a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts. Please use a tiny mnemonic alias for every table & use with every column.

Answer (score 1):

Helpful hints: Alias all your tables to make your code easier to read. Also, you are trying to return multiple columns with the same name, which can be a problem. **Alias column names in the results to avoid that issue.** Perhaps the IDE you're using doesn't like duplicate column names and giving you an issue.

You were very close to having it right.

```
create table marketing_interaction (
  marketing_interaction_id integer, 
  organization_id integer, 
  contact_id integer, 
  internal_person_id integer, 
  description varchar(50)
  );
  
insert into marketing_interaction values 
(1, 75, 18, 97, 'follow up with client');

create table person (
  person_id integer, 
  first_name varchar(20), 
  last_name varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into person values 
(18, 'John', 'Smith'), 
(97, 'Adam', 'Jones');

create table organization (
  organization_id integer, 
  name varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into organization values 
(75, 'acme corp');
```

```
select mi.marketing_interaction_id, 
 mi.organization_id, 
 o.name as org_name, 
 mi.contact_id, 
 p1.first_name as contact_first_name, 
 p1.last_name as contact_last_name, 
 mi.internal_person_id, 
 p2.first_name as internal_first_name, 
 p2.last_name as internal_last_name, 
 mi.description
from marketing_interaction mi
join organization o
  on mi.organization_id = o.organization_id
join person p1
  on mi.contact_id = p1.person_id
join person p2
  on mi.internal_person_id = p2.person_id;
```

| marketing_interaction_id | organization_id | org_name | contact_id | contact_first_name | contact_last_name | internal_person_id | internal_first_name | internal_last_name | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 75 | acme corp | 18 | John | Smith | 97 | Adam | Jones | follow up with client |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NScrL4_F)